# Python TypeError: string indices must be integers error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, hacker-news-api

I am trying to use ycombinators api in order to get the top news articles. However I keep on getting this error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Heres my code

```
articles_list = []
y= requests.get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json")
y = y.json()
print(y)
print("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + number +".json" +"?print=pretty")
for number in y:
    req = requests.get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + str(number) +".json" +"?print=pretty")
    req = req.json()
    print(req)
    break
for thing in req["url"]:
    articles_list.append(thing["url"])
```

I can not understand whats wrong....

Comment: I'm going to guess you have more than one url returned in your req.  Sharing a sample of your json response would help.  If `print(req[0]['url'])` works then that's your problem.

Comment: What does `print(thing)` on each iteration of `for thing in req["url"]:` give you? Is it a string? If so, can you see how `thing["url"]` might cause a problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response just didnt see your comment. Basiclly the outpoot is (shortened)[ 33525941, 33525923, 33525849, 33525846, 33525840, 33525830, 33524604, 33524589, 33524574, 33524563, 33524556, 33524507, 33524479, 33524330, 33524314, 33524300]
{'by': 'belltaco', 'descendants': 0, 'id': 33532043, 'score': 1, 'time': 1668004060, 'title': 'Bitcoin price dips under $17.6K June low as FTX nerves liquidate nearly $1B', 'type': 'story', 'url': 'https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-price-dips-under-17-6k-june-low-as-ftx-nerves-liquidate-nearly-1b'}